# What is going on with my dog

Tags: dogs, behavior

Details about dog:
•Female
•Rottweiler Mix
•5 years old

History:
Has never had anything like anxiety, has only lived in one place, was raised by my aunt (so not abuse or history of abuse), no changes in food or daily life, and is healthy. She has always been a chill and sweet dog.

Questionable behavior:
About 2 days ago she started whining all day. We gave her a doses of baby aspirin (did not do anything),made sure she has food and water, but when we take her out she starts digging like crazy (not weird behavior for her) in the pile of wood we have outside. When we inspected the pile we just found the hole she has been making. She has gone from this sweet and chill girl who has a motherly instinct for anyone, to this crazed dog who can't get comfortable, paces back n forth, whines all day, and is attached to her owner. Please if you have anything to say (expert or not) please help she is freaking me out

Comment: Is she neutered / spayed? This sounds like it could be an overreaction to her sexual hormones. And when was her last vet visit? Very sudden changes in behavior can always be a sign of a medical problem. Please stop giving her pills until you actually know what's wrong with her. Aspirin acts as a blood thinner and can lead to complications if she requires surgery.

Comment: Sudden change in behavior -> call the vet.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted in the comments, sudden changes in behavior should be discussed with your vet immediately. There could be a number of possibilities here, so you need to talk to your vet who is familiar with her medical history and can examine her and call for tests as needed.

As someone who has gone through something similar with a dog, I can provide the following thoughts, but please note I am not a vet, and this is not medical advice.

- exercise: is she getting enough physical and mental stimulation? anything changed in her typical regimen? Puzzle toys/feeders and other games can help provide additional mental stimulation and exercise. Licky mats also help dogs self-soothe (licking is soothing for them and it keeps them engaged when anxious)
- has anything about her normal routine changed? Dogs are very routine-driven, so even if it's not a direct change to her any change in the home can cause dogs to be upset or anxious (for example, did someone in the home recently return to the office?)
- re: sudden attachment, try having scheduled time with the dog where you're giving her undivided attention for an activity like chewing a bone or playing with a toy. if you can do this consistently each day and work into a routine, your dog will learn to expect that time each day. this can be soothing for the dog (and you!)

Other things to check and your vet will likely ask about:

- how is her appetite? eating and drinking normally?
- is she urinating normally? are bowel movements normal?
- is there anything in the wood pile that she could have gotten into?